# PHP password update form not writing to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Now I stuck at updating password area, I try to key-in new password, then I click update button but at database not updated, anyone here can help me where is the error?

This is my declaration of updating

```
    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
      $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    }

    if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE user SET password=%s WHERE password_hidden=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['password'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['password_hidden'], "text"));
```

And here is my form

```
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
<table border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td width="130"><span class="style5">New Password</span></td>
        <td width="15"><div align="center" class="style5">:</div></td>
        <td ><label><input name="password" type="password" id="password" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo $row_chgpswd['password']; ?>" size="20" />
        <input name="password_hidden" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_chgpswd['password_hidden']; ?>" />
        </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="26">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><div align="right">
          <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Change Password" tabindex="3"/>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is the input element named `emailtm`? In your form, you haven't included it. So probably that might be the issue.

You haven't included in the form, but you are accessing it in your php code via the `$_POST` !

`$_POST` is an associative array which contains the name-value pair of the input elements you have submitted via the form.

Comment: I've edit my coding up there, but still don't solve. my password not update in database.

Comment: echoing your old password in your HTML form, might not be a good idea. Anyway, have you tried debugging the code. I mean, echoing `$_POST['password']` and the other field to check whether both are correct values.

Comment: do you have an idea how to view user old password and at the same time user can update their new password as my code above?

Comment: If you wish to show the user their old password, then fetch it from your db and store it in a variable. Then echo it. Also, if you wish to show both oldpassword and newpassword(just after the user had updated), you have to write the code for the updation part, after the fetching part(of old password). But I won't recommend storing th e password as it is in the db. The best way to store user passwords is to hash them and store the hash value. Better protection!

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can also look at the apache log file to see if there is any error. Somehow, I see you need to enclose values of password and password_hidden in quotes in your query.

```
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE user SET password='%s' WHERE password_hidden='%s'",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['password'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['password_hidden'], "text"));
```